# Circle calculator not working correctly

Tags: python, if-statement

The code is written in **python 3.3** and only works for the first if statement, not acknowledging the other elif statements even if the if statement is wrong.

```
calccircle()
```

What data do you know? radius

```
Enter Diameter def calccircle():
      x = input("What data do you know? ")
      if x == "Diameter" or "diameter":
          a = int(input("Enter Diameter "))
          print("Circumference is", a * math.pi)
          print("Area is", math.pi * math.pow(a/2,2))
          print("Radius is:",a/2)
      elif x == "Radius" or "radius":
          b = input("Enter radius: ")
          print("Circumference is", b * 2 * math.pi)
          print("Area is", math.pi * math.pow(b,2))
          print("Diameter is", b * 2)
      elif x == "area" or "Area":
          c = input("Enter area: ")
          print("Circumference is", ((math.sqrt(c))/math.pi) * b * 2 * math.pi)
          print("Diameter is", math.sqrt(c) * math.pi * 2)
          print("Radius is", math.sqrt(c) * math.pi)
      elif x == "circumference" or "Circumference":
          d = input("Enter Circumference: ")
          print("Area is", math.pi * math.pow(d/math.pi,2))
          print("Diameter is", d/math.pi * 2)
          print("Radius is", d/math.pi)
```

It displays the input("Enter diameter: ") and doesn't pay attention to what I write or the if statements.

> calccircle()
>   What data do you know? **radius**
>   Enter **Diameter**

Notice I wrote radius, and the input("Enter radius: ") is supposed to run, but it doesn't.  Please help.

Comment: What language? I'm confused.

Comment: Python 3.3.  Sorry, I thought that I has mentioned that.  My mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
 if x == "Diameter" or "diameter":
```

looks to python like:

```
 if (x == "Diameter") or "diameter":
```

which, when `x != "Diameter"`, is like:

```
if "diameter":
```

which will always go through.

Python treats `False, None, "", [], {}, ...` and the like as `False` in the context of `if` statements (or if you call `bool` on them, or various other places), and most everything else as `True`. This is often handy, but can combine with a slight confusion about the `or` statement to make lots of people not used to Python make this mistake.

Instead, do one of these:

```
if x == "Diameter" or x == "diameter":  # most direct translation
if x in {"Diameter", "diameter"}:  # very slightly faster, a little less typing
if x.lower() == "diameter":  # also allows DIAmeter, etc
```

---

It's also worth noting that if you wrote something like

```
if x == ("Diameter" or "diameter"):
```

this would be the same as

```
if x == "Diameter":
```

since `"Diameter" or "diameter"` sees that `"Diameter"` is `True`ish, and so returns that.

Comment: In English, commas and "or" (or "and") can be used to list various alternatives. In programming languages, "or" never (or at least almost never) works that way. It's almost always a boolean operator. There are some common extra wrinkles such as short-cut evaluation, casting to booleans, and what Python does which are supposed to allow some useful tricks without breaking the normal pattern. In Pythons case, those extra tricks date from before the "x if c else y" syntax was added, and are mostly a broken way of trying to get the same effect - ie best avoided.

Comment: @user2070615 Glad I could help! In general, on SO, there's not much need to post your corrected code unless you have further problems with it, and in that case, you should edit it into your question rather than posting it as an answer. Also, when you're problem's resolved you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).